# Makefile optimization for quickly compiling a library as quickly as possible?

Tags: c, makefile

Are there any methods I can use to shave seconds off my library's compilation?

My old Makefile took 1.86s to run, up to 5.147 total.
After I changed

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Into:
        @$(CC) $(FLAGS) -c $(OBJ:.o=.c)

And added `@` to silence all the output, my new Makefile took 1.40s to run, up to 3.481 s total.

I'm wondering if there's any ways I can optimize my makefile to simply make it run faster or make it more "useful"? Where do I go to learn about micro-adjustments to get a slightly faster compiled program?

https://github.com/Hourai42/libft/blob/master/Makefile

```
NAME = libft.a
FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
CC = gcc
OBJ = ft_strrchr.o ft_putstr.o ft_strcmp.o ft_strlcat.o ft_memcpy.o \
ft_strequm.o ft_memmove.o ft_strsplit.o ft_strncpy.o ft_lstmap.o \
ft_lstadd.o ft_striter.o ft_strstr.o ft_isdigit.o ft_putnbr.o \
ft_memccpy.o ft_strdel.o ft_nmbwrd.o ft_memchr.o ft_bzero.o \
ft_isalnum.o ft_putstr_fd.o ft_lstiter.o ft_lstdelone.o ft_toupper.o 
\
ft_strcpy.o ft_lstnew.o ft_strdup.o ft_putnbr_fd.o ft_striteri.o \
ft_strmap.o ft_putendl_fd.o ft_memdel.o ft_strnstr.o ft_putchar.o \
ft_isascii.o ft_strlen.o ft_strsub.o ft_strnew.o ft_memalloc.o 
ft_putendl.o \
ft_strncat.o ft_itoa.o ft_strncmp.o ft_memcmp.o ft_strtrim.o 
ft_strequ.o 
\
ft_putchar_fd.o ft_memset.o ft_isalpha.o ft_strcat.o ft_tolower.o \
ft_strnequ.o ft_strjoin.o ft_atoi.o ft_strclr.o ft_strmapi.o \
ft_isprint.o ft_lstdel.o ft_strchr.o ft_mallocwrd.o ft_countplace.o \
ft_isprime.o ft_hassqrt.o ft_fibonacci.o ft_recursive_power.o \
ft_recursive_factorial.o

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): 
    @$(CC) $(FLAGS) -c $(OBJ:.o=.c)
    @ar rc $(NAME) $(OBJ)
    @ranlib $(NAME)

clean:
    @/bin/rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    @/bin/rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: clean fclean re
```

Comment: I would try `@$(CC) $(FLAGS) -c *.c` if you only have the above c files in your current dir. That would the substitution, but would scan the disk. Worth a try, but your makefile already seems super-optimized. you could also try to hardcode command paths to avoid path lookup...

Comment: How fast do you really need your program to compile?  Although it can happen, it's pretty rare for compilation speed to be worth optimizing.

Comment: I can believe that your new Makefile yields somewhat faster from-scratch compilation, but it's terrible for performing rebuilds when only a few source files have changed.  Possibly that's a problem inherited from the previous version, but in any case, fast *re*builds are usually much more valuable than fast from-scratch builds.

Comment: Ah, I should always have the -c files in the directory, but I was simply told that wildcards would cause errors so I wrote everything out. I don't really have a particular "need" for it to be faster, I think this is fine as it passed, but my friend's makefile was slow enough that his project was flagged as incorrect despite the fact that all his functions worked. I just have an obsession with maximizing things and seeing if I can do anything better, I guess. How can I focus on fast rebuilds rather than fast from scratch builds, then? Thank you.

Comment: If you care about speed, then make sure you get your dependencies rock-solid, and run make -j<how many CPU cores you have>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Redo only what needs to (huge improvement).
2. Use parallel make (significant improvement if run on a multicore CPU).
3. Invoke only one single shell per recipe (moderate to minor improvement).

Example:

```
NAME = libft.a
FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
CC = gcc
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS))

.PHONY: all clean ultraclean

all: $(NAME)

%.o: %.c
    @$(CC) $(FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    @ar rc $(NAME) $^ && \
    ranlib $(NAME)

clean:
    @/bin/rm -f $(OBJS)

ultraclean:
    @/bin/rm -f $(OBJS) $(NAME)
```

And then, if you have, let's say, 6 cores and hyper-threading:

```
$ make -j12
```

Note: of course, with parallel make, do not parallelize cleaning targets (`clean`, `ultraclean`) and building targets (`all`), as you do with your `re` target.